# SOLR / Lucene MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: solr, lucene

I wish to query a Lucene index  and ask the question "***..does the string ABC occur in Field A AND string DEF in Field B ...***"

**BOTH** conditions (*ABC in Field A and DEF in Field B*) must be true ....I've fooled around
with a few searches and don't seem to be hit the proper combination.

Any ideas / examples ...seems that the MultiFieldQueryParser may be the answer but I've had no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The standard query parser supports this sort of query, like:

```
+fielda:ABC +fieldb:DEF
```

The `+` character is the required operator, so this query will require a match on both `fielda:ABC` and `fieldb:XYZ`.

See the [query parser syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview), for more information.

`MultiFieldQueryParser` is used to automatically search for the same content in multiple fields, so not quite what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response ...I'm using a SOLR search in the browser and entering http://..../select?q=+fielda:ABC AND +fieldb:DEF ...this return anything with ABC in fielda OR DEF in fieldb  ...I've used Lucene searches in the past and assumed SOLR would work the same ...guess I was wrong.

Comment: Did you make sure the query was correctly [URL Escaped](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#NOTE:_URL_Escaping_Special_Characters)?  Losing `+` is a likely issue when not URL escaping the query.  Final query might look something like:  `q=%2Bfielda:ABC%20%2Bfieldb:DEF`. Also, `+this AND +that` probably works fine, but doesn't make sense.  `this AND that` is basically shorthand for `+this +that`, so I'd pick one or the other.  And I'd pick +/- syntax. It makes more sense for lucene, and is more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out on a SOLR browser search, the ***q.OP=AND*** on the URL will provide the ANDING condition I was looking for.